# How to show Country of Manufacture attribute in layered navigation?

Tags: product-attribute, layered-navigation, filter

I want to use *Country of Manufacture* attribute in layered navigation. I have set 'Use In Layered Navigation' Yes by editing the attribute from admin. but still it's not showing in layered navigation in frontend.

Can anyone help me on this issue?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Clear the cache and rebuild the indexes. Also make sure you have products that have values for the attribute in question.

Comment: I have cleared the cache and rebuild the indexes, and set the value for some products also but still the same issue.

Comment: Please checkout following url may be that help.
[http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/21702/how-to-display-core-country-of-manufacture-attribute-in-layered-navigation][1]


  [1]: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/21702/how-to-display-core-country-of-manufacture-attribute-in-layered-navigation